# Concurrency of Kafka streams topology with multiple output topics

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Given a Kafka streams topology which publishes messages to two different topics, are there any guarantees in which order various steps will be executed in these two branches or are those branches separated completely and executed in parallel?

### Example

```java
    KStream<..., ...> filteredStream = builder.stream("input-topic", ...).filter(...)...;

    filteredStream.mapValues(this::mapOne).to("output-topic-one", ...);
    filteredStream.flatMap(this::mapTwo).to("output-topic-two", ...);
```

In this example, will `mapOne` executed and publishing to *output-topic-**one*** be done **before** `mapTwo` is even getting called or messages are published to *output-topic-**two***? In other words, is there a guarantee that `mapOne` will be finished **before** messages are published to *output-topic-**two***?

### Topology Visualization

When looking at the visualization of the topology description (see at the bottom; made with https://zz85.github.io/kafka-streams-viz/) you can see the two branches. But you can also see these numbers in each bubble which might also indicate that there is an order of execution (1-4, then 5-6-7, then 8-9).

[image: kafka streams topology]

### Topology Description

```
Topologies:
   Sub-topology: 0
    Source: KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000 (topics: [input-topic])
      --> KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000001
    Processor: KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000001 (stores: [])
      --> KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000002
      <-- KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000
    Processor: KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000002 (stores: [])
      --> KSTREAM-MAP-0000000003
      <-- KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000001
    Processor: KSTREAM-MAP-0000000003 (stores: [])
      --> KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000004
      <-- KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000002
    Processor: KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000004 (stores: [])
      --> KSTREAM-MAPVALUES-0000000005, KSTREAM-FLATMAP-0000000008
      <-- KSTREAM-MAP-0000000003
    Processor: KSTREAM-MAPVALUES-0000000005 (stores: [])
      --> KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000006
      <-- KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000004
    Processor: KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000006 (stores: [])
      --> KSTREAM-SINK-0000000007
      <-- KSTREAM-MAPVALUES-0000000005
    Processor: KSTREAM-FLATMAP-0000000008 (stores: [])
      --> KSTREAM-SINK-0000000009
      <-- KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000004
    Sink: KSTREAM-SINK-0000000007 (topic: output-topic-one)
      <-- KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000006
    Sink: KSTREAM-SINK-0000000009 (topic: output-topic-two)
      <-- KSTREAM-FLATMAP-0000000008
```

Answer (score 1):

Kafka streams always guarantee the Topology order. It is always passing the message in a topology, that topology has edges and nodes. Those edges and nodes added to the topology as you define it in the application.

In your case `filtered stream` go through the `map values branch` in the topology until that path is end (in your case sink -> topic one).

Then it continue with `flat map branch`. until the sink to topic two.

It is ordered correctly with that IDs.

`0000000004` -> `0000000005` -> `0000000006` -> `0000000007`

`0000000004` -> `0000000008` -> `0000000009`

For more information go through the Kafka source code [internal topology builder](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/2.8.0/streams/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/processor/internals/InternalTopologyBuilder.java)

And refer [this](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-kafka-streams/content/)